# Setting session id on laravel test

Tags: laravel, session, phpunit

I'm trying to write a regression test for a http request. It's a cart/checkout controller.

At some point the controller checks if there's a Cart with a `session_id` that equals the session id of the request. Somewhat like `Cart::whereSessionId(session()->getId())->first()`.

Unfortunately, the session id of the request is not the same as the one generated for the actual test, which means that even if I use a factory to create a Cart like so: `$cart = factory(Cart::class)->create(['session_id' => session()->getId()])` it will never find that record.

So how can I set the session id for the request?

Answer (score 3):

I understand this thread has been around for a while and properly isn't helpful to OP but I encountered this issue today and thought I would post my solution, Add this into your test method:

```
Session::shouldReceive('getId')
       ->andReturn('my_mocked_session');
```

Then whenever you use `Session::getId()` it'll return 'my_mocked_session'.

Comment: Session::partialMock()->shouldReceive('getId')->andReturn('my_mocked_session');

if you need actual session to be filled with other data